# Get next Wednesday date after a date with R

Tags: r, lubridate

i have an assignment for students and I would like to add a column to this table that includes the date of the Wednesday following the date specified in column `date`.  Students are supposed to look at news coverage on the day specified in `date` and then present their results on the next class, the next Wednesday.

```
#generate all possible days 
dates<-seq.Date(from=as.Date('2019-09-11'), to=as.Date('2019-10-31'), by='days')
#These are the group names
groups<-paste('Group', seq(1,6,1))
#sample 6 random dates and pair with a group
df<-data.frame(date=sample(dates, 6), group=groups)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
df$date + (4 - match(weekdays(df$date), d)) %% 7
#[1] "2019-10-30" "2019-10-30" "2019-09-25" "2019-10-02" "2019-09-18" "2019-10-09"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the date of next Wednesday using lubridate and a vector of date difference (`date_diff`) to the next Wednesday for each weekday (`wday()`) in a custom function the following way:

```
next_wed <- function(x) {

  date_diff <- c(3:1,7,6:4) 

  x + date_diff[lubridate::wday(x)]

}

df$next_wednesday <- next_wed(df$date)
```

**Update**

Below is a broader solution, a function that calculates the next weekday specified as 1 = Sunday to 7 = Saturday.

```
next_wday <- function(d, w) {

  d + (seq(w - 1, length = 7) %% 7 + 1L)[8 - lubridate::wday(d)] 

}
```

The next Wednesday can be found with:

```
df$next_wed <- next_wday(df$date, 4)
```

Comment: If you want to fancy up your broader solution, make it similar to the `next_wed` function and get rid of ifelse, `date_diff = (7:0 + wday) %% 7; date_diff[date_diff == 0] = 7; next_day = date + date_diff[wday(date)]`. (Sorry to keep commenting, but I like this method a lot and it's fun to think about.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but without the ifelse a Workaround using add_date is needed. Otherwise the function won't find the next Wednesday on a Wednesday.

Comment: I also enjoy thinking about this problem, since I find myself dealing with similar issues at work. Another idea was to [shift the 1:7 sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894598/shift-a-sequence-by-certain-interval-in-r?noredirect=1#comment102211001_57894598) according the the target weekday, but I haven't come up with a nice approach yet.

Comment: A simple way to do the shift would be to start with `z = rep(7:1, 2)` and pick the right `i` for `z[i:(i + 7)]` to work.

Comment: I now figured a way of using a shifting 1:7 sequence, however it is still somewhat verbose (but, for what it's worth, it does'n require ifelse).

Comment: Finally came up with a one liner without if / ifelse.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with `ceiling_date()`

```
library(lubridate)
#This sets the start day of the week to be Wednesday (7 is the default, Sunday)
options(lubridate.week.start=3)
#This assigns each day in df$date to the next unit above it and stores it as df$presentation.
df$presentation<-as.character(ceiling_date(as.Date(df$date), unit=c('week')))
#Restore default
options(lubridate.week.start=7)
```

Comment: You can set the week.start as an argument to ceiling date, you don't need to change it globally

Comment: I removed the data generating code copied from the question - it makes it clearer at a glance what the answer is