# Shift a sequence by certain interval in R

Tags: r

What would be the easiest way in R to "shift a sequence by a certain interval" (I am not sure whether this is the correct terminology). For example lets assume we have a function shift_seq() which works like this:

```
x <- 1:7
shift_seq(x, 1) 
> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1
shift_seq(x, 2)
>  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2
```

Does a function such as the fictional `seq_shift()` from above exist?

**Update:**

Apparently this question had been already asked using a slightly different terminology. Thanks @akrun for referencing the questions. Nevertheless, user tmfmnk has provided a new very concise way of shifting a sequence (see accepted answer below). In the answers to the previews questions two packages are referenced which contain a similar function: `permute::shuffleSeries()` and `binhf::shift()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be:

```
n <- 3
c(x[-c(1:n)], x[1:n])

[1] 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

In a form of a function:

```
shift_seq <- function(x, n) {
 c(x[-c(1:n)], x[1:n])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
foo = function(x, n){
  c(x[(n+1):(length(x))],x[1:n])
}

foo(7:1, 3)
4 3 2 1 7 6 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `head` and `tail` -

```
shift_seq <- function(v, s) {
  c(tail(v, -s), head(v, s))
}

x <- 1:7

shift_seq(x, 1)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 1

shift_seq(x, 2)
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
x = 1:7

shift_seq = function(x, n){
    ind = (seq_along(x) + n) %% (length(x))
    ind = replace(ind, ind == 0, length(x))
    x[ind]
}

shift_seq(x, 2)
#> [1] 3 4 5 6 7 1 2
shift_seq(x, -2)
#> [1] 6 7 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>